# Basic Compilation Error in Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I'm just learning all this so I am making a novice mistake here I don't see. Any ideas? This is what I get when I try to run:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0050: Inconsistent accessibility: return
>   type 'dsUserActivity' is less accessible than method
>   'clsDataLayer.GetUserActivity(string)'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 21:     public static dsUserActivity GetUserActivity(string
>   Database)

Comment: Better to share some related code

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess without seeing the code. Probably GetUserActivity is a public method but dsUserActivity is not a public class. Try adding "public" in front of the dsUserActivity class declaration.